# Is it possible to let both console sound and VLC to be heard in the speakers plugged to the console with QjackCtl?

Tags: debian

I have a very simple radio on Internet and to make it work I have a laptop with Debian Buster, a small Behringer Xenyx 1202 mixer for connecting microphones and some instruments, and a external sound card Berhringer U-Control UCA202 to let the signal or audio be sent from the mixer to the laptop. The software: Internet DJ Console and QjackCtl.

It works perfect, but now I have the need for sending, for example, the audio of a video or a oog/mp3 file I have in my laptop to the same mixer I use for capturing the sound in orden to hear it in my speakers. Why? Because I also use this laptop for projecting some slides with sound and movies on the video beam, and I need it to be sound in the speakers.

I've installed PulseAudio Jack Sink to let the sound be played in my laptop, a youtube video or movie in VLC, in the same time IDJC is working. And I've plugged a line cable from the headphones output of my laptop to the mixer, but no succedd, the sound does'nt sound.

Is it possible to let both console mix sound (I know this one does, of course) and VLC to be heard in the speakers plugged to the console mix?[image]

Comment: Troubleshooting: 1. Do you hear anything if you plug actual headphones into your laptop instead of the line cable? 2. Is the laptop mixer for the headphone output at nonzero level and unmuted? 3. Try using your external sound card for the output, too, so that Jack needs to handle a single device only. Check 1. and 2. again. 4. Use the jack output module of VLC to remove PulseAudio from the picture. 5. Try other media players with native jack output.

Comment: @FerencWágner, 1) Neither headphones nor cable line works when pulseaudio-jack-sink is able, but to make it work I have to disable module-jack-sink and module-jack-sink in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and `pactl set-default-sink jack_out` script in Jack Setup. This way is OK, but I won't be able to use JACK and Pulseaudio/ALSA at the same time on the same audio device, or to play a audio file in VLC when IDJC in ON. 2) The audio mixer is on 100%. 3) My external sound card only send the console mixer signal through it, not the VLC audio. 4) Doesn't work. 5)Which other? I've used VLC all my life.

Comment: Not sure I understand you. If you start `jackd` with your external sound card in full duplex mode (input and output), can you get any native jack players sound your speakers? VLC has native jack output module, try that first.